# finding node values in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

How does one fine the node  author, node group (type) and the node content in drupal

```
$author = user_load($node->uid);

$node->type

$node->body
```

Are there alternate ways of finding these values?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to "find" values it to simply dump the available objects, arrays, or other variables. My personal favorite way to do that is to install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), then use the [dpm()](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) function to output variables into the message area of the page. The [Drupal for Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) module is similar, but can be used to send variables to the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console. Drupal 7 includes a useful [debug() command](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/6/debugging-drupal-7).